# How to UN-log a client if the application crashes

Tags: sql, crash, client, lazarus, freepascal

In my application, I use access database in a server, in which I log the user activity of all my clients, logging in when they start the client app and logging out when they close the main form.

I do that changing a field in the database to: logged - YES, or logged - NO

But when the application crashes for random reasons, the client doesn´t un-log, how I can do to un-log the client in case of an exception (or crash)?

Using Lazarus and ZEOS / SQL / ODBC / ADO to comm with access.

Thanks,
Leonardo

Answer (score 2):

I believe with a timeout. In general. If you have say MySQL server and you throw in 'A logged in' 'A logged out', than you'd probable need some nasty middleware which will do those two records for you: log in is straight forward. Log out: IF on event xyz customer has logged out, log out. Every hour say receive a ping on whoever is logged in. Or on MAX COOKIES TIMOUT TIME.... haven't received a ping? Log out. So you'd probably keep KEEP ALIVE times for your logged in users and once a while do a batch job which logs them out.